# Should @@rowcount persist from a trigger into the proc its calling?

Tags: sql-server-2008, stored-procedures, triggers, persist, rowcount

In other words, if I have a trigger that calls a proc; should I be able to check `@@rowcount` in the first line of the proc?  And should `@@rowcount` have a value based on the last SQL statment executed in the trigger?

I'm debugging a proc which I did not write.  First line of the proc is

```
if @@rowcount=0
RETURN
```

The proc is called by a trigger.  The last thing the trigger does before it calls the proc is to:

```
INSERT INTO #temp_table (some fields...)
SELECT some fields.. FROM inserted

EXEC SOMEPROC
```

What's happening is that `@@rowcount` in the proc is always 0 and the proc ends before it does anything.  The fix is pretty easy in that I'd just move the `@@rowcount` check into the trigger and take it out of the proc.

But its curious to me why it was written this way in the first place.  Almost like it used to work at some point and now it doesn't?  I just wanted to check and see if maybe there was some change in behavior between SQL2005 and SQL2008 or some system setting that got flipped.  Or did one of my predecessors just write bad code that never worked?

Answer (score 0):

I don't like to use `@@ROWCOUNT` for checking the status of a trigger. Too many other statements in the procedure and in between can reset that to 0.

For example:

```
SELECT TOP (10) name FROM sys.objects;
SET ANSI_NULLS ON;
SELECT @@ROWCOUNT;
----
0
```

Rather, I would check the `inserted`/`deleted` pseudo-tables. So, for an insert or update trigger:

```
IF EXISTS (SELECT 1 FROM inserted)
BEGIN
  ...
```

For a delete trigger:

```
IF EXISTS (SELECT 1 FROM deleted)
BEGIN
  ...
```

Comment: Thanks for the answer but I wasn't really looking for a solution per say.  I'm more interested in whether or not this should be working.  I agree that this is not the best solution and I will be changing it.  However I'm asking if the value of @@rowcount should persist from the trigger to the proc its calling.

Comment: No, `@@rowcount` is reset every time you issue any kind of statement. The EXEC call in the trigger resets it, for example. If you want you can change the procedure to accept the count as an optional parameter, then set some `SET @localvariable = @@ROWCOUNT` immediately after the statement in the trigger that populates rowcount, then you can pass that value into the procedure no matter how many statements occur in the meantime.

Comment: Actually I think I just figured it out based on something Aaron said in his post.

The proc is running

set nocount on

set transaction isolation level read uncommitted

before the @@rowcount check.

When I flipped them it worked.

So the answer is that yes; the value of @@rowcount does persist between a trigger and a proc.

However, I agree with Aaron in that this is not a good way to check to see if the trigger did anything.